# Transforming random variables to be independent

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose we have random variables $X, Y: \Omega \to \mathbb R$ that are not independent. Under what circumstances does there exist an *invertible* transformation $T: \mathbb R \times \mathbb R \to \mathbb R \times \mathbb R$ such that the random variables $(A, B) := T(X,Y)$ are independent?

When $X$ and $Y$ are jointly Gaussian with covariance $\Sigma$, standard whitening transformations $T = \Sigma^{-1/2}$ satisfy this requirement, as decorrelated jointly Gaussian variables are independent. However, in the general case, what can be said about such transformations?

Comment: You can linearly transform them to be uncorrelated.  This is the best you can do.  Whether or not independent would be hard to prove.  If not independent, then non-linear transformation might work.